# Is it possible to duplicate an object property in a mongoose schema with the 'default' property when creating the object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, request

I have a Customer object with multiple properties like address, shippingAddress and billingAddress and if the customer does not pass any additionally shipping/billing address data I need the address data to be duplicated into this properties as default.

I already have a solution and it works but maybe someone has a cleaner approach. I tried it with `default: this.address` but it does not work.

/model/customer.js

```
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    address: {
        type: addressSchema,
        required: true,
    },
    shippingAddress: {
        type: addressSchema
    }
});

customerSchema.methods.setShippingAddress = function(address, shippingAddress) {
    return (shippingAddress) ? shippingAddress : address;
}
```

/routes/customers.js

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let customer = new Customer({
        address: req.body.address
    });

    customer.shippingAddress = customer.setShippingAddress(req.body.address, req.body.shippingAddress);

    customer = await customer.save();
    res.status(200).send(customer);
});
```

So when the API receives a POST request I actually just check if a shippingAddress property is passed in the request and if not then I just overwrite the `.shippingAddress =` with the `address`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the function-based default value described at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions. In your case it would be

```
const customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    address: {
        type: addressSchema,
        required: true,
    },
    shippingAddress: {
        type: addressSchema,
        default: function() { return this.address; }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no error but it does not copy the ```address``` data into the ```shippingAddress``` property. I already tried to create a static function in the addressSchema (class) to set the values but I cannot touch the passed data from the request into it...

Comment: My bad.... I got distracted by the ```() =>```. I forgot that it is not possible to use the ```this``` statement in an arrow function. So I acutally changed it into ```default: function() { if(!this.shippingAddress) return this.address; } ```

Comment: @AlexSchwifty Ah, you are right about the arrow function and this-binding. I have updated the answer according to your comment. Is the `if(!this.shippingAddress)`-part needed? The default should only be applied if the property is without value.

Comment: You are right, it is just a bad habbit from my view to always double check... the if statement is not needed. Thank you!